# What was the morning star (Pulsar) called in Arabic *BEFORE* Quran was revealed?

Tags: quran, arabic

Surah aṭ-Ṭāriq speaks of piercing/morning star, commonly translated as Pulsar. My question is what was this morning star called before Quran was revealed? I mean, the star was always there, so Arabs must have used a word/name to refer to it. Was it Tariq? Thanks

Comment: The qur'an and any revelation before came in the language of the people it addresses. Else how should they understand the message of the revelation?

Answer (score -1):

Tariq : from طارق.  طرق means sounding like a jackhammer  same as pulsar, discovered only recently and  ثاقب means piercing ! These 2 descriptions were made in the Quran inChapter 86 some1440 years ago. These descriptions could not have been from Muhammad himself but from The Creator of all the galaxies ! Another perpetual miracle of the Quran! God bless you all!
Dr Abdollah Gilani